# Showing three lines pass throw one point (external)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

ABC is a triangle with acute angles. Take points A′, B′, C′ outside
of the triangle such that:

1. BA′ = CA′, CB′ = AB′, AC′ = BC′;
2. the triangles ABC′, BCA′ and CAB′ do not intersect the triangle ABC;
3. these triangles have angles 90◦ at the vertices A′, B′ and C′.
   Prove that the lines AA′, BB′, CC′ pass through one point

Im attempting to use Ceva's theorem to solve the question, the approach I took was trying to show AC'F and FC'B are congruent triangles which leads to C'F cutting AB into two equal parts hence being a median and then I could use Ceva's theorem but Im a little stuck in this approach. Are there any suggestions on how I can move forward on this?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the lengths in your diagram, shouldn't $A'C$ be about the same length as $A'B$? Are those meant to be angles? The angles seem to be divided equally. Usually people use three points to specify an angle.

Comment: Yes they are meant to be of equal length, the diagram just does a bad job at depicting that!

Comment: That's a seriously bad job indeed. $BC'$ is more than twice as long as $AC'$.

Comment: Hint: If $BA' = CA'$ then $A'$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ and if $\angle BA'C = 90°$ then according to Thales's theorem $A'$ must also lie on the semicircle over $BC$ (respecting condition 2). Btw: $AA'$ is not a median

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to use the Ceva's theorem and the following observation: prove that $$
\frac{AF}{FB}=\frac{S_{AC'C}}{S_{BC'C}}=\frac{AC\cdot\sin\angle CAC'}{BC\cdot\sin\angle CBC'}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since Richrow has already provided a proof using Ceva's theorem, I would like to provide a proof using geometric transformation.

Notaion: Instead of $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$, I feel $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ more convenient.

In the figure, we are going to prove that $AX \bot YZ$ and hence $AX$ is an altitude of $\Delta XYZ$

To achieve this, we rotate $YA$ and $YZ$ $90^o$ about $Y$ to obtain $YC$ and $YG$ as shown.

Note that $\angle YCG=\angle ZAY=A+90^o $, $\angle XCY=C+90^o$

Hence $\angle XCG=360^o-(A+90^o)-(C+90^o)=B$

Together with $XC=\frac{BC}{\sqrt 2}$ and $CG=AZ=\frac{AB}{\sqrt 2}$,

we have $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta GCX$

Comparing length ratio, $XG=\frac{AC}{\sqrt 2}=AY$

Note also that by similar triangles, $\angle XGC=A$

and $\angle YCG=90^o+A \implies \angle YCG+\angle YGC=90^o-A$

Thus $\angle AGY+\angle AYG=A+90^o-A+90^o=180^o$

therefore $XG // AY$ and hence $AYGX$ is a parallelogram.

Thus $AX$ is parallel  to $YG$

Since $YG \bot YZ$, therefore $AX \bot YZ$ and $AX$ is an altitude of $\Delta XYZ$

By similar arguments, we can prove that $BY$ and $CZ$ are altitudes of $\Delta XYZ$.

Hence the three lines $AX$, $BY$ and $CZ$ will meet at the orthocentre of $\Delta XYZ$.